# Rails + Devise + Add User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a problem with my Rails app login with Devise.

I have the devise user for login and i create a new scaffold user to manage the user.

my routes.rb are like :

```
devise :users
resources :users
```

The problem is when i add a new user when i'm logged with an existent user, the data is not saved in the DB.

if i add a new user when i'm loged out, the user are added to the DB.

to add the new user i use this link : new_user_path.
So thats mean it use the resources users

my users_controller

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
  redirect_to users_url, :notice => "User created."
 else
   render :action => 'new'
 end

end
```

in my application_controller i added this functionnality

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
company_id = resource.company_id
@company = Company.find(company_id)
puts @company.subdomain
root_url(:host => @company.subdomain + "." + request.domain + '/companies/' + @company.id.to_s)
end
```

when i add the users when i'm loged in i have that in the server log

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create User", "authenticity_token"=>"6p7qqcu3x8WAJ7eWdtwJLeJQV1lj9IXtomtzxUpTx3k=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"usersubtype_id"=>"", "username"=>"3423", "last_name"=>"", "company_id"=>"1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"foo@bar.com", "first_name"=>"", "usertype_id"=>""}}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

i dont know why that works when i'm not logged, but not when i'm logged.

Thanks for your ideas.

EDIT : I checked for devise :registerable in my user model. here is what i have in my model.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 belongs_to :company
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :owner, :usertype_id, :usersubtype_id, :company_id
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your routes are both pointing to the exactly same place. In this case, both points to the `Devise::RegistrationsController` from Devise.

What you have to do is just say in your routes that you want to point your Users scaffold to a specific controller.

Go to console and type `rake routes` and see how they are showing to you and then, change your routes to:

```
devise :users
resources :users, :controller => "users"
```

and type again `rake routes`and see the difference between both.

Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: no difference between. each devise and resource have the same routes.

Comment: Another question, if it's a routes problem, why when i'm not logged the add user works and no when i'm logged? i see too that the update works logged or not.

Comment: I wish I could just keep upvoting this answer. Most of the suggestions out there are to rewrite the Devise Registrations. This fix, of pointing `resources :users` to the correct controller, is *so* much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Strangely, this issue came back for some reason. I still had conflicting /users routes (visible in `rake routes`). I ended up having to set `devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]` and add custom routes for `devise/registrations#create` etc to the `devise_scope :user` block with lines like `post "create-registration" => "devise/registrations#create", :as => :user_registration`. Here's a view of the customized `routes.rb` file: https://gist.github.com/4703255

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `devise(:registerable)` in your user model?  If so, you may want to use `new_user_registration_path` instead of `new_user_path`.  I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but it could be a step in the right direction.

Comment: hmm no? I must use devise(:registerable) ? whats that change between logged user and not logged user?

Comment: I have updated my post. Yeah i have devise :registerable. And i don't want to use new_user_registration_path because i don't want to use the default form.  But thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If using default devise form was the only problem for you,
 you should have generated devise views with

```
'rails generate devise:views'
```

and then find the form inside,
views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb and edit it.

You shouldnt have generated scaffold for a user,instead you could have either inherited devise registration controller or created only a User controller.

Scaffold creats controller,model,as well as a migration.Do you need two databases to manage users?

Comment: no, i need only 1 db, i created the scaffold because when we edit a user, the password are encrypted and cant see it.

Comment: Why do you need to see the password?Any user knows their password,if they forget, devise provides a recoverable module to recover them.I would suggest you to read about devise and its wikis thoroughly.Also passwords should always be encrypted,overwise anyone can get hold of it through history,cookies etc

Comment: @neimad  http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function  For more information on what you're supposed to do with passwords.